# Check if user is using mobile device

Tags: symfony, user-agent

I need to check if a user is using a mobile device upon connecting to the website.

I need to make an eventListener further on.

in the [Symfony doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation.html) there is a passage where actually you can check this `$request->headers->get('User-Agent')`

Is there a simple way to do that?

**--- EDIT ---**

this is the code I wrote so far. I'm missing maybe on how to pass it to the controller?

**service**

```
  template.loader:
      class: ST\BackofficeBundle\EventListener\DeviceListener
      tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.view, method: onKernelView }
```

**listener**

```
    class DeviceListener
{
    public function onKernelView(getResponseEvent $event)
    {
       $event->getRequest()->getSession()->set('mobile', true);

       $response = new Response();
       $response->setContent($event);

       $event->setResponse($response);
    }
}
```

Am I on the right track ?

Comment: I think your question is too wide, read about how services work first of all. moby.loader is a service defined in the answer you posted, so you'd have to define that service which is and instance of your loader class

Comment: ok thank you, I will try to narrow it

Comment: "I need to check if a user is using a mobile device" — Why? "Mobile device" is almost never a useful piece of information to know. What do you really care about? Display size? If the screen is a touch screen? If they are on a slow network connection? On a metered network connection? On an unreliable connection? Are capable of running a .exe file if they were to download one? Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a look at https://github.com/kbond/ZenstruckMobileBundle code

It creates an EventListener here:
https://github.com/kbond/ZenstruckMobileBundle/blob/master/EventListener/RequestListener.php

And based on that, overwrites the twig render here:
https://github.com/kbond/ZenstruckMobileBundle/blob/master/Twig/TwigEngine.php

Both things get wired up through
https://github.com/kbond/ZenstruckMobileBundle/blob/master/Manager/MobileManager.php

Comment: Thank you for your help, I will try to apply that tomorrow :)

Comment: I understood a bit how that works but the "twig render" what does it actually do? because at first I really want to know how to get to know if the user is using a mobile. So I created an event listener and the mobile manager. i do not need that line `$request->headers->get('User-Agent')` ?

Comment: The twig render chooses a different template if the mobileManager injected service says it's mobile. How you figure if it's mobile or not, it's up to you, you could as well use User-Agent on your event listener. In this case they use a mobileManager to figure that out.

Comment: thank you for your explanation. I updated my post. I miss an argument in the service (do i need a service by the way?) and how can I know now if the user is using a mobile? its the first time im doing this kind of function and im a bit lost I admit and because i'm looking for a simple way to detect if the user is on a mobile device.

Comment: I'm afraid you have too many questions and you should ask them separately, but I'll try to answer here. You can check if it's a mobile by checking the User-Agent if you want. The idea is that in your event listener you check that, and then pass it on. You could pass it in many ways, one could be altering the request object for example, and another could be setting some parameter in a service where you can check later on, as this MobileManager. The Twig Render is just to write up everything is it checks on the MobileManager when you do render so everything becomes transparent for you.

Comment: i see, well it was my question about how to use `user-agent` in order to detect if the user have that, how to pass it on etc.. I followed your instructions on `Zenstruck`but even if it is really good i have a hard time to just detect if user use mobile, where to add `user-agent`, should I put things in the controller etc. But I appreciate your help, thank you

Comment: Well, I'm trying to explain how to do it right. To achieve what you want you can just register your event listener, check for the user agent there and then from there do something like:

$event->getRequest()->getSession()->set('mobile', true);

Then you could check in your controller that value and decide how to render based on that parameter. Later you'll want to avoid to check that on every method, so you can start investigate what I proposed first.

Comment: Ok i see. Do I need to setup a service too? Because I added one like this `template.loader:
      class: ST\BackofficeBundle\EventListener\DeviceListener
      arguments:
        -
      tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.view, method: onKernelView }` argument is empty because i didn't know what to put it in

Comment: You don't need an argument unless you add to your your class a constructor, have a look at http://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher.html

I think the question was answered and we should not extend the discussion here. Start a new question more specific if you need more help.